# Host asp.net site as HTTPS in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, iis-7, hosting

I have developed and deployed ASP.Net site in IIS 7.  It is working fine.  Now my client is asking me to run the application using https only.  So I decided to run the host under SSL.

But i am new to SSL or https. In many places it ask me to install the certificate.

> How can i just enable a SSL without using X509 Certificates in IIS 7?.

Is there any steps/articles explains simple SSL with out X509 Certificates to run the sites with https?  Or using Development Certificate will bring any issues?

Comment: You can't. X.509 certificate is required for SSL/TLS to function properly in most environments including ASP.NET web sites. You can generate and use a self-signed certificate, but it won't be accepted by default by browsers. Your better option is to learn basics.

Comment: @Ravi, yes :) But i think i can manage with development certificate i guess.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I think using IIS Administrative Tools i can generate self-signed certificate by giving site name and the site id. Thanks. Let me try it.